# Import docker image to gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have a docker image which is supposed to provide my team with grading capabilities for a series of assignments pushed to gitlab by students. I have been given some "runners" that are supposed to be virtual machines where computation can happen. Now I need to connect the docker image with the runners.

To do so, another team uses a setup with gitlab "container registry" which I don't have right now. Instead my colleague suggests I can just import the docker image into gitlab, perhaps using "scp".

How would I do that? scp user@ip:file?

**Try**

```
sudo scp user@user:localFile user@ip:remoteFileLocation
```

answers:

ssh: connect to host user port 22: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

You can [save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) Docker images as tar file, transfer the saved file to the runner(s) and then [load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) them there.

Comment: I did the docker save with docker save -o ./file.tar docker-image. But the question is how do I transfer the saved file to the runner(s) on gitlab?

Comment: In this case your question has nothing to do with `docker` or `gitlab`… and we don't know if/how you can access your runner(s) host(s). If you are using the SaaS version then this won't work btw.